# Why are Oracle table/column/index names limited to 30 characters?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, size

I can understand that many years ago there would be this kind of limitation, but nowadays surely this limit could easily be increased. We have naming conventions for objects, but there is always a case that turns up where we hit this limit - especially in naming foreign keys.

Does anybody actually know why this isn't a bigger size - or is it bigger in 11g?

---

Apparently the answer is that it will break currently scripts that aren't defensively coded. I say that is a very worrying thing, Oracle is trying to be **the** database, surely this is the kind of thing that you must constantly improve, otherwise your product will die the death of a thousand cuts.

Whenever I see this kind of objection in-house, I think it is time to bite the bullet and sort it out. If people are running scripts that they do not check or maintain when they upgrade Oracle versions, then let them suffer the consequences of that choice. Provide them a compatibility flag, up the size to 4000, then save me the wasted time when I'm creating objects of having to constantly count to 30 to check the name is 'OK'.

Comment: Since there needs to be a limit? Make it 64 characters and you'll probably find someone asking why it's not 128 etc.. How long is a piece of string?

Comment: True, but 30 is a very short piece of string. Why cant it be 4000 - the size of a Varchar2 - does Oracle really care how long it is once it has parsed the query?

Comment: @TheChairman PostgreSQL limits me to 63 characters, and I have never had a problem with that length limit. It's large enough that my names will fit, and if I am considering a longer name, it's time to start thinking about the negative impact on readability. On the flip side, I *often* run into name length limits in Oracle and am forced to *reduce* the readability of my name because of the 30 character limit. A few people might complain about a 64 limit, but *a lot* of people already have problems because of the 30 character limit. It's about meeting 99% of the use cases, and Oracle fails here.

Comment: Come on, Oracle, you have become a Dinosaur! Microsoft is doing a good job to make SQL server more friendly. Now relax the name length restriction.

Comment: Fast-forward to Oracle 12cR2, it's now 128 bytes instead of 30 :-)
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/newft/new-features.html#GUID-64283AD6-0939-47B0-856E-5E9255D7246B

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I believe it's the ANSI standard.

**EDIT:**

Actually, I think it's the SQL-92 standard.

A later version of the standard appears to optionally allow for 128 character names, but Oracle doesn't yet support this (or has partial support for it, insofar as it allows 30 characters.  Hmmm.)

Search for "F391, Long identifiers" on this page...  http://stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/ap_standard_sql001.htm

(Looking for a ref)

Comment: Wow - good answer. I've tried looking at the SQL-92 standard but cant actually find this part - do you know of the exact statement that defines this (teach a man to fish, and all that)

Comment: Hmm, that's not how I read that document. It says to me that F391 is an item in the SQL/Foundation spec (whatever that is), and that Oracle has partial support for it, with a 30 character limit.

Comment: I'd guess SQL/Foundation is one part of the SQL standard. I agree. From the title of the section, the 30 character limit seems to be the reason why oracle does NOT comply to that spec. (Or only partially)

Comment: Partially compliance. What a joke. "our screws partially comply to the metric standards, except they are not metric."

Comment: I haven't read the F391 spec in detail, but I'm assuming (maybe incorrectly) that "Long identifiers" means an increase in identifier length from 30 to 128.  So saying that you "partially" support this by allowing 30 characters is a bit cheeky.  You don't support the new standard, you still support the old standard (albeit 25% of the way to the new standard)   Did that make sense?!!?

Comment: No - it didn't make sense. But I think I understand the business speak

Comment: The SQL-92 standard is here http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt , but if you read section "17.1 Description of SQL item descriptor areas" it says identifiers like names and schemas must allow at least 128 characters.

Comment: For the record, _ISO/IEC 9075-2:1999 (E) ©ISO/IEC_, section _5.2 <token> and <separator>_, _Conformance Rules_ states: "Without Feature F391, ‘‘Long identifiers’’, in a <regular identifier>, the number of <underscore>s plus the number of <identifier part>s shall be less than 18."

Comment: The very fact that Oracle fanboys don't see the usefulness of 30+ char identifiers is disturbing.  "Make your names meaningful/descriptive, use underscores instead of camel case, and stay under 30 characters".  That would *never* go over 30 characters. Amirite? More like abbreviate your abbreviations and when none of the names make sense, spend all day reading/updating the documentation.

Answer (score 47):

In addition to cagcowboy's point that it derives from the SQL standard (historically, I suspect that Oracle's decision lead to the SQL standard since Oracle predated the standardization of SQL), I would wager that a large part of the reluctance to allow longer identifiers comes from the realization that there are millions of DBAs with millions of custom scripts that all assume that identifiers are 30 characters long.  Allowing every line of code that goes something like

```
  l_table_name VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
  SELECT table_name
    INTO l_table_name
    FROM dba_tables
   WHERE ...
```

to suddenly break because the DBA 15 years ago used VARCHAR2(30) rather than `DBA_TABLES.TABLE_NAME%TYPE` in the script would cause massive revolt.  I would wager that Oracle alone has thousands of places where this sort of thing has been done over the years in various packages and components.  Retrofitting all that existing code to support longer identifiers would be a tremendous project that would almost certainly generate **way** more costs in developer time, QA time, and newly introduced bugs than it would generate benefits.

Comment: +1 This is almost certainly one of Oracle's many legacy design cripples.

Comment: Surely its time to grow a pair and increase it - add a flag so that DBAs can refine it back down to 30. Legacy issues like this should always be confronted and sorted otherwise you end up crippling the whole code base, and people will just move onto something else

Comment: +1 Am sure this is part of the reason.  I'm sure I'll have coded VARCHAR2(30) somewhere...

Comment: Not just millions of lines of DBA written code, but plenty of oracle internal code no doubt too. This topic came up in a session with steven feuerstein and he said he didn't think they would ever change it.

Comment: They couldn't exactly trumpet it as a new feature, either... they'd spend a lot of time extending the limit, and then announce "you can now use names longer than 30 characters!". They'd be the laughing stock.

Comment: Its true.  Oracle is probably too far gone to fix.  Time to just move on to solutions built on modern technology.  Oracle: "we have been the name to trust for decades, and we haven't changed!"

Comment: If you're still using 15 year old scripts, **something is extremely wrong**. Also, fixing them would be a one time cost (possibly with some more for continued maintenance), while developers will continue to waste time needlessly crafting horribly abbreviated names indefinitely. @skaffman They're already a laughing stock for *not* fixing it (and a host of other design decisions that are pathetic in the modern era, like no boolean or auto-incrementing types), as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @jpmc26 to a millenial maybe, but from a big banks/insurance companies/universities/governments perspective there is nearly-30 year old  COBOL and mainframe code still being run in production today (because if it's still functional enough to satisfy the original spec...). There are "modern" ERPs tightly coupled to Oracle being used today that contain legacy COBOL ports and Pro*C everywhere (Ellucian Banner is very guilty of this, but I have seen it in the Oracle and PeopleSoft ERP backends too).

Answer (score 16):

I was looking this up and found this question via Google, but also found out that as of Oracle 12c Release 2 (12.2), this is no longer strictly the case.
(https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/long-identifiers-12cr2)

> At some point every DBA or developer will have hit a point where the 30 character limit for object names has caused a problem. This limit can be extremely painful when doing migration projects from SQL Server or MySQL to Oracle. In Oracle Database 12cR2, the maximum length of most identifiers is now 128 characters.

This is a new feature in 12.2, according to (http://blog.dbi-services.com/oracle-12cr2-long-identifiers/). According to that post, 12.1 was still limited to 30 characters.

---

Edit: Here's a link to the official Oracle documentation explaining the change. (https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/exadataexpress-cloud/CSDBF/longer-identifier-names.htm#CSDBF-GUID-F4CA155F-5A37-4705-8443-0A8C9E3F875C)

> Starting with Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2), the maximum length of identifier names for most types of database objects has been increased to 128 bytes.

Comment: 128 bytes/4 bytes (Unicode) = 32 Characters. At least my understanding is that 4 bytes for non Unicode characters isn't that uncommon? I have to wonder if that merely means that they're supporting Unicode now? Just like `VARCHAR2(2)` doesn't mean 2 characters but 2 byte.

Comment: I see your point, but the characters vs bytes does depend on your database character set. That setting determines the encoding for the char datatypes (such as varchar2) as well as the encoding for db identifiers. This is contrasted with the national character set, which is used for nchar datatypes. So yes, if you have an encoding such that your identifiers are using 4 bytes per character (assuming such can be used as the DB character set), you would now have 32 instead of 7. But I think for most use cases identifiers would be single-byte characters.

Answer (score 6):

Given the practical necessity of identifier length limits, good design restricts the length of actual names to avoid hitting the ceiling when the names are combined with each other and with prefixes and suffixes.

For example, a convention of naming foreign key constraints

```
FK_<table1>_<table2>
```

limits table names to 13 characters or less; most databases are going to need more prefixes and suffixes, further limiting the length of table names.

Answer (score 6):

All of these 'constraints' are left over responses to limitations imposed by processor architectures that hail from the 70s.
Since that time processors have evolved to the point that these limitations are no longer necessary; they are just left over.
However, changing them is a BIG deal for the writers of the RDBMS. Since these length limitatons affect everything downstream changing it willy nilly to accomodate say a longer procedure name can and probably will break a lot of other stuff such as exeception reporting, the data dictionary, etc., so forth and so on.
I would require a major re-write of the Oracle RDBMS.

Answer (score 5):

Constraint violations get reported in SQLERRM which is limited to 255 characters, and which most clients use to make errors visible. I suspect increasing the allowable size of constraint names significantly would impact the ability to report on the violations (especially where a constraint violation has been bubbled up through a few layers of PL/SQL code).

Comment: So, uh, make that table wider, then?

Comment: It isn't a table, but how client software actually gets errors from the database.

Comment: @skaffman SQLERRM length is an API/ABI specification. Changing this would meaning having to patch every OCI driver on the planet (else buffer overrun). They could slot the change to the client to increase the buflen in OCI 13 first and the server in something like Oracle 15, where OCI 10 clients would no longer be supported, I suppose. (Maybe they are even considering it now, but oracle major version releases only every few years; and then we may still run into script/application upgrade pain when apps get migrated to different server/client).

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the 30 character identifier length comes from COBOL which was standardised in the late 1950s. Since COBOL programs were the main user of SQL (and SEQUEL before that (and QUEL before that)), this must have seemed like a reasonable number for the identifier length.

Comment: I believe the first version of Oracle was written in Fortran, which I think has an identifier length limit of 31. Maybe that's relevant.

Answer (score 2):

All the above comments are right, BUT you need to keep in mind the performance cost of longer names.  In the early 1990's, when Informix set up huge billboard "Informix Faster Than Oracle!" on route 101 next to Oracle headquarters, Informix allowed table names only shorter than 18 characters!   The reason is obvious -- table names in their literal form (i.e. as actual names rather than 't138577321'or something like that)  are stored in the Data Dictionary.   Longer names equal larger Data Dictionary, and since the Data Dictionary is read each time a query requires a hard parse, a larger data dictionary equals poor performance...

Comment: There's absolutely no reason for exact matching of short strings to be a bottleneck in any modern software unless you are doing it billions of times—which isn't the case in query parsing. Size-performance considerations may have been significant when this part of Oracle was first designed, but they're not really relevant these days.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to the question is that Oracle style is inherited from older ideas in which 30 seemed a lot, and much more would have increased the risk of unpinning the dictionary cache from real memory in typical databases.

In contrast, ODBC namespace comes from a very different place, where data sets are extracted rapidly by parsing a table in an Excel sheet and automatically build database tables with column names taken from sheet table headings. Thinking like that leads you to allowing identifiers that even contain embedded carriage returns, and of course special characters and mixed case. It's a sensible abstraction because it models the way today's data analysts think.

Never mind SQL92, it's ODBC compliance that really matters to today's universal database, and other vendors have addressed this better than Oracle. Even Teradata, for example, which isn't seen by many as a pervasive player, caters for TWO namespaces, with and without the quotes, the former with a 30 char limit, the latter a full ODBC implementation where weird long identifiers are catered for.

Even in the traditional large database arena, 30 characters is often a problem where names are to remain meaningful, consistent and memorable. Once you start to design specialising structures with role-named inheritance you start abbreviating abbreviations, and consistency soon dies, because for example the same root identifier rendered as a table name or a column name will in one case need further abbreviation and in the other not. If real users in significant numbers are invited on to such layers the consequences are very poor usability, and fortunately for any ageing database the main drive now is to separate user from database via object layers and BI tools.

This leaves the database layer to the DBA and the data architect teams, who are perhaps not that bothered. Working out abbreviation schemes is still a job for life, it seems.

That Oracle has not addressed this old limitation perhaps reflects mostly on the fact that it is not (yet) losing much business to its competition when it can't directly port database designs built using longer identifiers.

Comment: Not to Oracle. ODBC is a Microsoft baby, not a Java one. It Is *still* a separate helper lib linked against OCI (look at how instantclient is deployed - in order to get ODBC working with instantclient you need both the OCI driver and the ODBC instantclient zips). Oracle's primary client platform (besides legacy Pro*C/C/C++) is JDBC, which is directly linked to OCI, not ODBC.

Answer (score -7):

ok, the limitation exists....

but do you really NEED more than to 30 character to name a table/index/column??

when writing queries, with that limitation I STILL find some column/table names annoying. If the limit were higher I might run into tables that required a query like:

```
select unique_identifier_column, 
time_when_the_user_remembered_to_change_the_row_in_the_receipt_table, 
foreign_key_to_the_ap_invoice_distributions_history_table_related_to_the_all_rows_table 
from ap_invoices_really_really_all_all_rows_present_in_this_ebs_table.
```

I apologize for the huge words :P

Comment: It would be nice to  be able to name foreign keys with the names of both tables and columns they join - therefore when a foreign key exception is thrown you don't have to look up the columns that caused the failure. Then again Oracle could just tell you that info...

Comment: There are many reasons why we need more than 30 characters, although usually 30 characters are enough. Sometime a table name need to be verbose enough to be meaningful. For example, I have this table call sch_PatternRunTimeException, it is exactly 30 character long. Now, I need to add a mirroring table call sch_DevPatternRunTimeException. This extra 3 characters naming standard isn't working for Oracle, MSSQL has no problem. This is forcing me to come up with a new name. Renaming table is doable, but it will impact our customers operations, which we try to avoid.

Comment: If in 99.9% percent of the possible cases +30 characters are *annoying* doesn't mean they'd come in handy the other 0.1%.

Comment: Ahhh the slippy slope argument.  A limit of only 4 alphanumeric chars would get us over 1 million table combinations so nobody really "needs" more than 4.  Yet here we are.  And it's not really 30 characters, it's less than 30 characters since my pascal case naming convention has to dumped with the lack of case sensitivity and replaced with underscore delimited names.  Combine that with various prefixes/suffixes and you're lucky to have even 20 chars.  Who wouldn't rather a robust index name echoed with a violation error over a hodgepodge of abbreviations and underscores?

Comment: Agreed this is not addressing the issue. Normally human beings don't need longer column names, but there are lots of cases where object names are automatically generated.