# ORA-00972 identifier is too long alias column name

Tags: sql, oracle, alias

i have a query like :

```
SELECT column as averyveryveryverylongalias (more than 30 characters)
   FROM Table_name
```

it returns the error **ORA-00972 identifier is too long** , is there any tip to make it work without making the alias shorter?

Comment: Hi, in  my case <tableName>.<propetyName>_<columnName> after the dot is longer that 30 character, Can you solved your problem? How?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

No, prior to Oracle version 12.2, identifiers are not allowed to exceed 30 characters in length. See [the Oracle SQL Language Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm#sthref727).

However, [from version 12.2 they can be up to 128 bytes long.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/exadata-express-cloud/csdbf/longer-identifier-names.html) (Note: bytes, not characters).

Comment: out of curiosity, does anyone know where this limitation comes from, and how come the limit has never been relaxed ? It really strikes me that none of the million-dollar paying customers of Oracle *ever* requested such a feature (now don't get me wrong, I am pretty sure there are some deep technical reason, but still..)

Comment: Okay, I could have asked SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378133/why-are-oracle-table-column-index-names-limited-to-30-characters

Comment: I also encountered this situation. I have a table column with name length=32. But why on earth is a table column name allowed to be more than 30 characters, while at the same time an identifier is not? These limits should go hand-in-hand, right? How can this situation arise at all?

Comment: @Vering Is it more than 30 characters or more than 30 bytes?  There is a weird bug where an identifier can be slightly more than 30 bytes if the last character is multi-byte.

Comment: @JonHeller: I'm quite sure it was 30 / 32 characters

Comment: I guess this is a legacy issue. To avoid backward compatible issue, it's not updated. But 30 is too short today.

Answer (score 13):

The error is also caused by quirky handling of quotes and single qutoes. To  include single quotes inside the query, use *doubled* single quotes.

This won't work

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml("Select ....") XML from dual;
```

or this either

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('Select .. where something='red'..') XML from dual;
```

but this DOES work

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('Select .. where something=''red''..') XML from dual;
```

Comment: The markup changed my example it should be something equals single quote single quote red single quote single quote

Answer (score 5):

The object where Oracle stores the name of the identifiers (e.g. the table names of the user are stored in the table named as USER_TABLES and the column names of the user are stored in the table named as USER_TAB_COLUMNS), have the NAME columns (e.g. TABLE_NAME in USER_TABLES) of size Varchar2(30)...and it's uniform through all system tables of objects or identifiers --

```
 DBA_ALL_TABLES         ALL_ALL_TABLES        USER_ALL_TABLES
 DBA_PARTIAL_DROP_TABS  ALL_PARTIAL_DROP_TABS USER_PARTIAL_DROP_TABS
 DBA_PART_TABLES        ALL_PART_TABLES       USER_PART_TABLES 
 DBA_TABLES             ALL_TABLES            USER_TABLES           
 DBA_TABLESPACES        USER_TABLESPACES      TAB
 DBA_TAB_COLUMNS      ALL_TAB_COLUMNS         USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
 DBA_TAB_COLS         ALL_TAB_COLS            USER_TAB_COLS 
 DBA_TAB_COMMENTS     ALL_TAB_COMMENTS        USER_TAB_COMMENTS 
 DBA_TAB_HISTOGRAMS   ALL_TAB_HISTOGRAMS      USER_TAB_HISTOGRAMS 
 DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS  ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS 
 DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS   ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS      USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Argos reporting system as a front end and Oracle in back.  I just encountered this error and it was caused by a string with a double quote at the start and a single quote at the end.  Replacing the double quote with a single solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently upgraded springboot to 1.4.3, you might need to make changes to yml file:

yml in 1.3 :

```
jpa: 
  hibernate: 
    namingStrategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

yml in 1.4.3 :

```
jpa: 
  hibernate: 
    naming: physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Answer (score -1):

As others have referred, names in Oracle SQL must be less or equal to 30 characters. I would add that this rule applies not only to table names but to field names as well. So there you have it.