# ORA-00972: identifier is too long with oracle image from sath89:oracle-12c:latest

Tags: oracle, identifier

i am using docker oracle image from sath89.

**describe all_tables** gives following output

```
Name                      Null?    Type          
------------------------- -------- ------------- 
OWNER                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128) 
TABLE_NAME                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128) 
TABLESPACE_NAME                    VARCHAR2(30)  
CLUSTER_NAME                       VARCHAR2(128) 
IOT_NAME                           VARCHAR2(128)
```

Now when i am running the following code

```
CREATE  table ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTTESTINGORACLE(
ID INT
);
```

it is saying identifier is too long . An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-00972 identifier is too long alias column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085562/ora-00972-identifier-is-too-long-alias-column-name)

Comment: Hi, my problem is i am using latest oracle 12c image and also describe all_tables says maximum table_name size to be 128 as i have mentioned in my question, still it is saying the "identifier too long" error. This is the issue.

Comment: You need Oracle version 12.2

Comment: But it is saying that table_name size is 128 .. so we may sure from there it is oracle version 12.2

Comment: @user10237300 Try querying `V$VERSION` just to be sure.  Maybe Oracle changed some of their column sizes before they changed the max identifier limit?

Answer (score 0):

Works OK for me:

```
SQL> select * From v$version;

BANNER                                                                               CON_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production              0
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production                                                    0
CORE    12.2.0.1.0      Production                                                        0
TNS for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production                                            0
NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production                                                    0

SQL> CREATE  table ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTTESTINGORACLE(
  2  ID INT
  3  );

Table created.

SQL> desc all_tables
 Name                                                  Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------- -------- ---------------------
 OWNER                                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 TABLE_NAME                                            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 TABLESPACE_NAME                                                VARCHAR2(30)
 CLUSTER_NAME                                                   VARCHAR2(128)
 IOT_NAME                                                       VARCHAR2(128)
 STATUS                                                         VARCHAR2(8)
 PCT_FREE                                                       NUMBER
 PCT_USED                                                       NUMBER
 INI_TRANS                                                      NUMBER
<snip>
```

Please, post the same demonstration (edit the question).