# "ORA-00972: identifier is too long" inserting Oracle BLOB using Node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle

i have base64 string (pdf) and want to insert that into oracle blob in node js.
Tried with Creating a buffer from the base64 string and encoded the buffer as a utf8 string, but received below error. Please let me know the solution.

Error: ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Comment: Please show us your code. Why do you try to encode pure ASCII into UTF-8? It is useless.

Answer (score 1):

No, prior to Oracle version 12.2, identifiers are not allowed to exceed 30 characters in length. See the Oracle SQL Language Reference.

[ORA-00972 identifier is too long alias column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085562/ora-00972-identifier-is-too-long-alias-column-name)