# How to increase identifier in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, identifier

I installed Oracle 11gR1 but I usually faced with error messaage

> identifier too long

Is a solution to increase identifier? 30 character is too short for my standard in naming of tables and sp

Answer (score 7):

The 30 character limit is not something you can adjust.  It is something that is built in to Oracle.  You'll need to adjust your naming convention.  There is another thread discussing [why Oracle identifiers are limited to 30 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378133/why-are-oracle-table-column-index-names-limited-to-30-characters).