# Why is there a maximum length for stored procedure names?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are Oracle table/column/index names limited to 30 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378133/why-are-oracle-table-column-index-names-limited-to-30-characters)

When writing a stored procedure in Oracle, I chose a particularly descriptive name, and when attempting to update the script I was informed the name was too long.

```
37  15  PLS-00114: identifier 'blah_blah_blah_blah_blah_blah' too long
```

Why is there such a restrictive limit on stored proc names? Is this just specific to Oracle or is this common in other db systems?

---

Sorry for the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378133/why-are-oracle-table-column-index-names-limited-to-30-characters)

Comment: In SQL Server it is `128` characters as that is the max length for a `sysname` (the datatype used in the system base tables)

Comment: That's a lot better than 30 in Oracle, as I quickly found out.

Comment: Because Oracle hails from the days when 30 characters was considered to be more than enough! After all, with file names of 8 characters, 30 is a ton!

Comment: @JWiley: better? - I don't think a 128 char sproc name is particularly desirable. 30 seems nice and concise.

Comment: @JonEgerton: as for me, 32 seems nicer :)

Comment: @JonEgerton Until you add "standard" prefixes, suffixes, and the like. Then you have 20 characters for your table name, and if you are trying to be descriptive, you fail. I want a many-many table between my ORDER_LINE_ITEM and PRODUCT_COMPONENT_MANIFEST tables... what do I name it? ORDER_LINE_ITEM_PRODUCT_COMPONENT_MANIFEST... Good luck reverse engineering OLI_PCM when there's 500 tables named like such...

Comment: @JonEgerton True, and I normally like to keep the names as short and concise as possible, but I did hit the max in one case, thus my question

Comment: @NWest thanks, not sure why that didn't pop-up for similar questions when I was composing this.

Comment: See:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378133/why-are-oracle-table-column-index-names-limited-to-30-characters

Comment: wow, +7 in 42 minutes, gotta be a record, no? (note to self, to improve my score quickly, bash Oracle ;)

Answer (score 5):

its actually 30 characters only in Oracle.

Every language/db has limit of length while defining names because the name of every object created in DB is stored in system tables and every column has some fixed length.

For performance, we keep the names short in case of DB.

Comment: hmm how does this answer *Why is there such a restrictive limit on stored proc names?*

Comment: As this pops up for MySQL too - for MySQL 5.7 (and probably bunch of other versions) it's 64 - manual - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: @ConradFrix I have mentioned that all db objects information is stored in system tables itself. Tables have column and they come up with some defined size, so that restricts to limit the content length to be stored.

Comment: I think the point is, why did Oracle opt for such a restrictive length? You say it's for performance. But I wonder what the performance hit would be if it was 60 or 64 or something. I frequently find 30 limiting, when taking into account code readability for others.