# How to throw a exception in function

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql

How can I handle the exception in a function call?
It has a separate function returning 1 or 0 depending on the argument used.

If the function `is_valid_eventTypesGeographicAddress` throws me 0 I want to throw an exception.

I have no idea how to do this in this syntax.

```
select is_valid_eventTypesGeographicAddress (in_type) from dual ,
             exception WHEN 0 then return  ('Invalid geographic address type');
```

Code does not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PL/SQL and its [RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#GUID-48F88C61-8CE9-4821-91CB-48A8F1BC09E1) to throw an exception. Here's an example:

```
declare
  myResult number;
begin
  myResult := is_valid_eventTypesGeographicAddress (in_type);
  if myResult = 0 then
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Invalid geographic address type');
  end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are PL/SQL constructs. You cannot implement exception handling in pure SQL. One option is to edit [the function so it raises the exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59320335/146325) - or write a wrapping function to do that.

```
create or replace function my_is_valid_eventTypesGeographicAddress (in_type in number) 
return number 
is
  rv number;
begin

  rv := is_valid_eventTypesGeographicAddress (in_type);

  if rv = 0 then
    raise_application_error (-20000, 'Invalid geographic address type');
  end if;

  return rv;
end;
```

You then call this version of the function:

```
select my_is_valid_eventTypesGeographicAddress (in_type) from dual;
```

This is a bit nasty. Generally we would expect our SQL to succeed or fail gracefully. So you might want to consider using your original function something like this ...

```
select * from dual
where is_valid_eventTypesGeographicAddress (in_type) <> 0
```

... and then routing control depending on whether the query returns a row.

But I suppose the real question is why are you trying to do this in SQL at all? It seems like it should form part of a stored procedure.

Comment: It won't work. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191299/why-is-there-a-maximum-length-for-stored-procedure-names

Comment: @dmak2709 - actually it depends on which version of Oracle we're using.  I have posted a working function called `my_is_valid_eventTypesGeographicAddress()` [on db<>fiddle XE 18c platform](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cced505a9ca59b6ee6393fc18101e8da) .  Oracle has  allowed [identifiers up to 128 chars since 12c R2](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/long-identifiers-12cr2). As the function name in the OP's question is **36 characters long** I feel confident that they are using a pretty recent version of the database

Comment: Still learning! :) ... But then also change the is_valid_eventTypesGeographicAddress call in the select statement and function. Although the function won't work because it will just recursively call itself. Am I right?