# how I can create synonym with "long refence object name"

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, ora-00972

After I created synonym, reference object name change;
my script:

```
create OR REPLACE SYNONYM [schema name].[synonym name] FOR [shema name]."long refence object name"@dblinkname;
```

After created I look for "long refence object name":

It's changed to "`/3248857lonobjectname`"

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT * FROM all_synonyms where owner = user;` on your database?

Comment: oracle version: 11.2.0.1.0 
other database: mssql

Comment: microsoft mssql

Comment: This is because Oracle object names are limited to 30 chars. See full answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `table_name` transformation comes from `"` you used in the synonym creation.

1. (You don't need the `[schema name].` prior the synonym name. ) ? or is it my Oracle release that prevent doing this?
2. I would **remove the `"` in the synonym creation**, except if you did use them for the table creation in the source db.

The right syntax for this should rather be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM [synonym name] 
  FOR [shema name].long_refence_object_name@dblinkname;
```

### edit

Now we now a little more.

- on the MSSQL, create a synonym too (adapt the syntax):

  ```
  CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM long_refence_object_name 
        FOR [shema name]."long refence object name"
  ```
- then you can use it so from Oracle

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM [synonym name] 
    FOR long_refence_object_name@dblinkname;
  ```

### edit2:

No, in fact this is your synonym name that is too long. But you cannot have objects with more than 30 chars. See [here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378133/why-are-oracle-table-column-index-names-limited-to-30-characters).

When I do this:

```
create or replace synonym "my" for SCHM.very_long_namevery_long_nameve@QGM1.WORLD;
```

My synonym works (I can access remote table), and I see it in user synonyms:

```
OPS$CHOJ04A my  SCHM VERY_LONG_NAMEVERY_LONG_NAMEVE QGM1.WORLD
```

But when I do that:

```
create or replace synonym "myvery_long_namevery_long_nameve" 
   for SCHM.very_long_namevery_long_nameve@QGM1.WORLD;
```

Then I can't access the object with

> ```
> ORA-00972: identifier is too long
> ```

and I this this horrible name:

```
OPS$CHOJ04A /1d23ec99_MYVERY_LONG_NAMEVERY  SCHM VERY_LONG_NAMEVERY_LONG_NAMEVE QGM1.WORLD
```

### Conclusion:

As far as I know, you can't have a synonym larger than 30 chars for any object in Oracle. This is a product limitation.

You still can use the synonym you created as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM "/1d23ec99_MYVERY_LONG_NAMEVERY";
```

Not sure it helps if you can't change the queries in your application.

Comment: but oracle change "long refence object name" to "/3248857lonobjectname"

Comment: the problem occur when "long refence object name" more than 30 
character